# Make center align the image of button in navigation bar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have the following xml file for navigation bar layout:

**navigation_bar.xml**

**EDIT:** I simplified this layout by removing table layout. but sill....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/NavigationBar" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/htc" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dummy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_home"
        style="@style/NavigationButton"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_home"
        android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and the following is my **styles.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="NavigationBar">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">45dp</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/top</item>
        <item name="android:dither">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="NavigationButton">
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    </style>   

</resources>
```

Also, following is the drawable button: **btn_home.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home_pressed"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home_pressed"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home_selected" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/home_default"
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="false" />
</selector>
```

And I get the following result:

[image: Screenshot of result]

See, the home button is displayed on top. But I want it to be center vertically. For that, I specified `<item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>` on `styles.xml` file. I tried `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"` also on `navigation_bar.xml`. But no result. How can I get the home picture to the center? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found a solution, although I don't feel it's best. Here is the solution I found out.

Using the values `wrap_content`, `fill_parent`, `match_parent` are all useless here. They always put the image on top whatever values I set for `android:layout_gravity` and `android:gravity`. And, at last, specifying the size of image as height has done the trick.

This is the new style for `NavigationButton` from `styles.xml`

```
<style name="NavigationButton">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
</style>
```

See the `layout_height`? It is now `25dp`. Also, following is the `Button` entry from `navigation_bar.xml`.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_home"
    style="@style/NavigationButton"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_home" />
```

And the result is

[image: Result of specifying exact height]

Answer (score 1):

You want a button with image only, so i will suggest you to use imagebutton instead of button.

And the solution in this code is

don't use android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_home"

instead use

android:background="@drawable/btn_home"

it will show the image in the vertical center

Comment: But that makes my button image stretched. Also i want a button that have different images for selected, pressed, and default states.

Comment: For having different images for selected, pressed and default states, This code should work because you are giving a selector drawable in the background.And for the problem that image stretched, i will suggest you to use imagebutton and then set the src to the selector drawable

Answer (score -1):

you will try this

```
 <Button
  android:id="@+id/btn_home"
  style="@style/NavigationButton"
  android:layout_centervertical="true"
  android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
  android:drawableTop="@drawable/btn_home"
  android:text="" />
```

Comment: I think there is no such attribute in android. It shows up the error `error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_centervertical' in package 'android'`

Comment: android:layout_centerhorizontal="true"

Comment: Yep! That also brings up the same error. `error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_centerhorizontal' in package 'android'`

Comment: I found out that these missed a caps. ie., I need `layout_centerVertical` and `layout_centerHorizontal`. But that too is not working.